# Copy a folder from server to Azure blob using django-storage

Tags: django, azure-blob-storage

How can I upload a folder **(media_root/folder)** which contains subfolder and files in it to Azure blob container? I can upload a file to Azure blob container using this:

```
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage

f = open('media_root/folder/file.csv', 'rb')
default_storage.save(path, f)
```

I have set [AzureStorage](https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/blob/master/storages/backends/azure_storage.py#L122) class in my settings.py.

`DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.azure_storage.AzureStorage'`

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [doc](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/azure.html) of django-storage shows, there is no method to upload a folder to Azure Storage blob, it just can be used to upload files.

If you want to upload a folder(*make sure it is not empty*) to Azure Storage blob, see the following code with Python.

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService,PublicAccess
import os

def run_sample():
    block_blob_service = BlockBlobService("your_account_name", "your_account_key")
    container_name ='test1'

    path_remove = "F:\\"
    local_path = "F:\\folderA"

    for r,d,f in os.walk(local_path):        
        if f:
            for file in f:
                file_path_on_azure = os.path.join(r,file).replace(path_remove,"")
                file_path_on_local = os.path.join(r,file)
                block_blob_service.create_blob_from_path(container_name,file_path_on_azure,file_path_on_local)            

# Main method.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_sample()
```

Comment: Thanks @pamela-pend, your answer was very helpful. Although I can not use BlockBlobService, because I was using old azure-storage library, perhaps 0.20.3. So I used this instead:


                    ffile = open(file_path_on_local, 'rb')

                    default_storage.save(file_path_on_azure, ffile)

                    ffile.close()